# What is the term for not believing in cause and effect after death?

Tags: karma

Is it just "annihilationism"? Whatever it is called, has is always been a heresy or wrong view?

I can't see how it must be annihilationism, because the budha answers that this dogma is wrong on the grounds that we already lack a self. Unless, that is, there is no empirical self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annihilationism - Ucchedavada - Taught by [Ajita Kesakambali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajita_Kesakambali)

This is considered a wrong view. Here is no heresy in Buddhism but any view or notion which you have not verified empirically at the experiential level but cling onto causes misery psychologically as in Buddhism.

Also see my answer in: [The "empirical self" in Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7187/the-empirical-self-in-buddhism)

Comment: ah but how can you verify that cause and effect lasts after death? at least, how can you do so and be rational ? please do add to your question :)

Comment: i added a little more to the question, thanks for any reply